# Move constructor for a custom container?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

is the move constructor for a class that holds a dynamically allocated array supposed to delete it? For instance I have:

```
template<typename T>
class MyVector
{
public:
MyVector()
{
data = new T[32];
capacity = 32;
size = 0;
}

MyVector(const MyVector<T>& o) //The basic copy constructor
{
capacity = o.capacity;
size = o.size;
data = new T[capacity];

for(int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
{
data[i] = o.data[i];
}
}

MyVector(const MyVector<T>&& o) //The move constructor
{
//What goes here?
}

private:
T* data;
unsigned int size;
unsigned int capacity;
};
```

I understand the move constructor is called when I do something like:

MyVector A;
A = MyVector(); //The one on the right gets a move constructor called?
So is it supposed to be identical to the copy constructor?

Comment: This is probably just a throw-away exercise, but your `Vector` won't work with types that have no default constructor. Real vectors don't create 32 new `T`s on creation; they allocate enough memory for 32 `T`s and then later will that memory with objects as needed via placement-new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the move constructor for a class that holds a dynamically allocated array supposed to delete it? For instance I have:

There is nothing to delete. The object is being *constructed* after all. All it should do is take the resources from the object on the RHS. It should leave the RHS in a reasonable state. For example,

```
MyVector(MyVector<T>&& o)
{
    data = o.data;
    o.data = nullptr;

    capacity = o.capacity;
    o.capacity = 0;

    size = o.size;
    o.size = 0;
}
```

Note that, in order for a move constructor to work, the parameter cannot be `const`. A move constructor modifies its argument.

Comment: oh, so it's like this:

MyVector(const MyVector<T>&& o) //The move constructor
{
data = o.data;
size = o.size;
capacity = o.capacity;

o.data = null;
o.capacity = null;
o.size = null;
}

?

Comment: @shortage_radeon I added an example. The invariants of the type should be respected, so you need to do something about `size` and `capacity` too.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, now I get it! So I had it the other way around, it's being called for the left side, stealing the data from the right side object.

Comment: @shortage_radeon Yes, the RHS is a temporary, and that binds to a `&&`, which means the move-overload is picked up. It is up to you to implement the move semantics correctly :-)